# Gitlab CI-CD via Docker : can't access Nexus in another container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-network, nexus3

I'm using Gitlab CI-CD to build some projects using a single Runner (for now) on Docker (the runner itself is a docker container, so I guess this is Docker in Docker..)

My problem is that I can't use my own nexus/npm repository while building...

```
npm install --registry=http://153.89.23.53:8082/repository/npm-all
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to http://153.89.23.53:8082/repository/npm-all/typescript/-/typescript-3.6.5.tgz failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 153.89.23.53:8082
```

The same runner on another server works perfectly, but it doens't work if running on the same server hosting the Nexus (everything is container-based)

The Gitlab runner is using the host network.
If I connect to the Runner and try to ping 153.89.23.53:8082 (Nexus), it works

```
root@62591008a000:/# wget http://153.89.23.53:8082
--2020-07-13 09:56:16--  http://153.89.23.53:8082/
Connecting to 153.89.23.53:8082... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7952 (7.8K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html                                   100%[===========================================================================================>]   7.77K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-07-13 09:56:16 (742 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [7952/7952]
```

So I guess the problem occurs in the "second docker container", the one used inside the runner... but I have no idea what I should change.

Note : I could probably set the gitlab runner to join the nexus network and use internal IPs, but this would break the scripts if the runner is started on other servers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution..

There is a network_mode settings that can be set in the runner configuration. Default value is bridge, not host..

```
**config.toml**
 [runners.docker]
    ...
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    network_mode = "host"
```